# How to use array data into query to get another data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

So here is my  PHP code:

```
$checkProject1Column = "SELECT * FROM tbl_studentchoice WHERE Project1 = '1'";
$resultProject1Column = mysqli_query($conn, $checkProject1Column);       
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultProject1Column)) {
            //Create an array of students
            $array[] = ['studentid' => $row['studentid']];
    }  
    //check marks database
    $checkmarks = "SELECT studentid,marks FROM tbl_marks";
    $checkResult = mysqli_query($conn, $checkmarks);
    if ($checkResult->num_rows >= 0){
        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($checkResult)){
            //Create an array of students
            $array1[] = [
                'marks' => $row1['marks'],
                'studentid' => $row1['studentid']
                ];
            }
        print_r($array);
        print_r($array1);
```

So I have 2 database tables. `tbl_studentchoice` and `tbl_marks`.
I created an array of students with a value 1 on `Project1` column. This is how my tbl_studentchoice looks like:

[image: projtbl].

So now that I have an array of studentid's. I want to get the marks of these students from another table (`tbl_marks`) which looks like this:

[image: marks]

and create a new array with only `studentid` with `Project1` value 1 and their marks. So basically I want to create an array like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [studentid] => c12558111 
        [marks] => 50
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [studentid] => c12558112 
        [marks] => 60
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the duplicate `$resultProject1Column = mysqli_query($conn, $checkProject1Column); `?

Comment: Actually no let me edit my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using two diffrent query??
you should join tables only write one query like this

```
select s.*,m.marks
  from tbl_studentchoice s, tbl_marks m
  where s.studentid = m.studentid
   and  Project1 = '1'
```

Complete Code

```
$query= "select s.*,m.marks
  from tbl_studentchoice s, tbl_marks m
  where s.studentid = m.studentid
   and  Project1 = '1'";
$result= mysqli_query($conn, $query);       
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  echo("<br/>Student ID = ".$row['studentid']);
  echo("<br/>Student marks = ".$row['marks']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I still do not have enough experience on PHP so I didn't know you could do a query like that. Can you explain the query to me I do not fully understand it. I have done and created the array and its good. I just want to understand that query a bit more.

Comment: It is like a inner join which joins two table with some condition, in your problem there were two table with one common column which is studentid so this query will merge data of two table whose studentid is same